# dev.clojurephant.clojure plugin using gradle kotlin dsl Error : Unresolved reference: aotAll

Tags: gradle, clojure, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've clojure project using gradle. The project is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-demo/blob/master/build.gradle).

The `build.gradle` is -

```
plugins {
    id 'dev.clojurephant.clojure' version '0.7.0'
    id 'application'
}

group 'org.example'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven {
        name = 'Clojars'
        url = 'https://repo.clojars.org'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.clojure:clojure:1.11.1'

    testRuntimeOnly 'dev.clojurephant:jovial:0.4.1'

    devImplementation 'org.clojure:tools.namespace:1.3.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

clojure {
    builds {
        main {
            aotAll()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm converting the above file gradle dsl. The project is on github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/clojure-gradle-kts-demo/blob/master/build.gradle.kts).
Below is the converted build file `build.gradle.kts` -

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("dev.clojurephant.clojure") version "0.7.0"
    id("application")
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven(url =  "https://repo.clojars.org/")
}

dependencies {
    implementation ("org.clojure:clojure:1.11.1")
    testRuntimeOnly ("dev.clojurephant:jovial:0.4.1")
    compileOnly ("org.clojure:tools.namespace:1.3.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0")
}

clojure {
    builds {
        main {
            aotAll()
        }
    }
}


application {
    mainClass.set("main.main")
}
```

The below clojure extension is giving error -

```
clojure {
    builds {
        main {
            aotAll()
        }
    }
}
```

The error is -

> - Where:
>   Build file '/Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/clojure-gradle-kts-demo/build.gradle.kts' line: 25
> - What went wrong:
>   Script compilation errors:
>
>   Line 25:         main {
>   ^ Expression 'main' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
>
>   Line 25:         main {
>   ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
>   public val DistributionContainer.main: NamedDomainObjectProvider defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
>   public val SourceSetContainer.main: NamedDomainObjectProvider defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
>
>   Line 26:             aotAll()
>   ^ Unresolved reference: aotAll
>
> 3 errors

Comment: try `getByName("main")`